# How to join two tables and create new column?

Tags: postgresql

Using PostgreSQL 10.4.

I am trying to JOIN two tables and create a new Array field that would hold the result of some query.

Table A:

```
- id
- image
- difficulty
- answers (this is the new array field to create)
```

Table B:

```
- id (foreign key that references table a's id)
- name
```

I would like to put Table B's 'name' fields of the matching ID of Table A's answer's array. How can I accomplish this/and with what query?

edit: I know how to do a JOIN. I am asking what is the way of creating a new column that would hold an Array of values while doing a JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

`Select * from A, B where A.id = B.id`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need either a standard (AKA inner) join
which will only show records where the id exists in both table a and table b

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.image,
       a.difficulty,
       a.answers,
       b.name
FROM   a
       JOIN b
           ON a.id - b.id
```

or alternatively, a left join which will show all the records in a and those in b that don't have a matching id value will be null

```
 SELECT a.id,
        a.image,
        a.difficulty,
        a.answers,
        b.name
  FROM  a
        LEFT JOIN b
            ON a.id - b.id
```

It's hard to say which one you require from the information provided but I think that is what you want